# Android: How to detect if chrome browser is in incognito via accessibility service

Tags: android, google-chrome, accessibility, incognito-mode

I have an app that uses accessibility service to extract URLs that are visited in the Chrome browser on Android. I would like to filter out URLs visited while Chrome is in the incognito mode. I assume it is possible because SecureTeen somehow appears to do that, and they do it via the accessibility service.

The layouts of Chrome in incognito mode and regular mode are identical. The only way I currently see is to detect the "Close all incognito tabs" notification and stop logging anything for some time, like 30 minutes. Is there a better and more reliable way of doing it?

Comment: There are many Web browsers for Android. Your question implies that there is only one.

Comment: @CommonsWare, good point, I updated my question. I only need it to work for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `AccessibilityService`, you better be listening for [AccessibilityEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) of notification type. Accessibility service will give you to retrieve package name of the notification, text etc.

[NotificationListenerService](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bbcccc162d55f19e30fced510a701d44e96e86f8/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ServiceTabLauncher.java) is another way to listen for chrome activity notification.

Head [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bbcccc162d55f19e30fced510a701d44e96e86f8/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ServiceTabLauncher.java) for more about Chrome package name.

Comment: I am listening to the NOTIFICATION_CHANGE event, but it doesn't trigger for the "Close all incognito tabs" notification.
Package name of chrome is the same whether it is in incognito mode or regular, so it also doesn't help :(
To clarify, I need to find a way to distinguish whether Chrome current is in the incognito mode or not.

Comment: @Ishamael did you figure this out?

Comment: @CamHart, it's been a while. I think what sort-of worked was to use the notifications API instead of NOTIFICATION_CHANGE accessibility event. Notifications API, if I remember right, was actually showing "Close all Incognito tabs" notification. The drawback is that now you need to ask separately for accessibility and notifications permissions.
Also Android was sending emails to all the apps that use Accessibility indicating that they will soon revoke ability to use Accessibility API for anything but, well, accessibility. So if you plan to use it for something else, it could be a problem.